# Best developing practices for MySQL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, cross-platform

Heyho,

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform app, that should manage different SQL data. My question is now:

What are the best practices for developing e.g. an iPhone app, in which an user logs in and only those data will be shown, that belongs to him? Especially security aspects are interesting for me.

Thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the seperation of the iOS app and a web service running on a your server. Instead of letting the app communicate with the SQL database directly it only communicates with your web service. You web service now decides what will visible to the client.

For the communication between the server and the client I would base on HTTP (see [REST Tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/restful-api-server-doing-it-the-right-way-part-1/)) like nearly all services too (including Facebook, Twitter, ...).

Comment: That's interesting. I will give it a go :-)

Comment: Okay I looked at it but this seems a bit confusing to me. Is there any possibility to add authentication mechanisms via user-password combinations stored in MySQl database?

Comment: No, the only way you wouldn't create a very, very, very easy to abuse security issue is not to access the MySQL server by any client running on the users device.